# How to generate a row number in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using pig for data preparation, and I faced a problem which seems easy but I can't deal with:

for example, I have a column of names

```
name
------
Alicia
Ana
Benita 
Berta 
Bertha
```

then how can I add a row number for each name? the result would be like this:

```
name    |  id
----------------
Alicia  |  1
Ana     |  2
Benita  |  3
Berta   |  4
Bertha  |  5
```

Thank you for reading this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to enumerate rows in Pig Latin. At least, I couldn't find an easy way. One solution is to implement a separate MapReduce job with single Reduce task that does the actual enumeration. To be more precise,

Map phase: assign all rows to same key.
Single Reduce task: receives single key with an iterator to all rows. Since reduce task will run just on 1 physical machine and "reduce function" will be called just once, local counter inside the function solves the problem.

If the data is huge and impossible to process on single reduce machine, then default MapReduce Counters on master node may be used.

Comment: Thank you Shatlyk, I didn't find the way in Pig Latin neither. Yes your idea of using only 1 reduce node can solve the problem, although it's not a really parallel algorithm

Comment: As the reducer need to process the data which has the same size as the whole mapper input, it will turn to be a bottleneck of the map-reduce program. I think it's very hard to implement a really parallel program like this as the tasktrackers can't maintain a global variable^^ BTW, finally I solved this problem by just using a java program on a single machine, it's fast  :)

Answer (score 10):

Pig did not have a mechanism to do this when you asked this question. However, Pig 0.11 introduced a [RANK operator](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2353) that can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

sketch idea, assuming that the "name" column we want to order by is numeric and not a string.
also assuming nice non-skewed distribution.

1. WITH_GROUPS = foreach TABLE generate name, name / 100 as group_id;
2. group WITH_GROUPS by group_id;
3. PER_GROUP = generate group, count(*);
4. ACCUM_PER_GROUP = cross join PER_GROUP with itself, calculate accumulative count per group;
5. cogroup ACCUM_PER_GROUP with WITH_GROUPS by group_id;
6. in the reducer run a UDF that assigns each row an id starting from this group accumulative_count

Answer (score 1):

@cabad

On the surface it does appear that the RANK operator would work but you are not guaranteed to have an increasing row id without providing some constraints on your data.

The problem comes from any rows which are provided to the ranking operator that are equal would share the same rank.  If you can meet the guarantee that no two rows have equal fields used for ranking then this approach might work, but I think I'd put it in the "square peg round hole" approach.

See this example from the [docs] http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#rank (ranks 2, 6, 10) :

```
C = rank A by f1 DESC, f2 ASC;

dump C;
(1,Tete,2,N)
(2,Ranjit,3,M)
(2,Ranjit,3,P)
(4,Michael,8,T)
(5,Jose,10,V)
(6,Jillian,8,Q)
(6,Jillian,8,Q)
(8,JaePak,7,Q)
(9,David,1,N)
(10,David,4,Q)
(10,David,4,Q)
```

Comment: For the use case described by the OP, a simple RANK A; would work.